# ¿Cómo realizo este ejercicio son Switch?

Tags: java, if

Bien, estoy en primer semestre de Universidad y estamos actualmente viendo la programación en java con Switch y nos encargaron realizar ciertos ejercicios, en particular, tengo duda con el siguiente:

> Elaborar un algoritmo para calcular e imprimir el precio de un terreno
>   del cual se tienen los siguientes datos: largo, ancho y precio por
>   metro cuadrado, si el terreno tiene más de 400 metros cuadrados se
>   hace un descuento del 10% si el terreno tiene más de 500 metros
>   cuadrados el descuento es del 17% y si tiene más de 1000 metros
>   cuadrados el descuento es del 25%.

El caso es que no sé como utilizar el Switch, ya que estuve investigando si es posible realizar Switch con invertalos como

```
case 400-500:
System.out........
```

Pero no da, y no se como realizarlo con Switch. Así que decidí realizar el código de esta manera.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Tereno
{
    public static void main (String args [])
    {
        int largo, ancho, preciometro, area;
        double descuento, preciototal, total;


        largo = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca el largo del terreno"));
        ancho = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca el ancho del terreno"));
        preciometro = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca cual es el precio por metro cuadrado"));

        area = largo*ancho;
        preciototal = area*preciometro;


        if (area>400 && area<500)
        {
            descuento = preciototal*.10;
            total = preciototal-descuento;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se aplica un descuento de: 10%");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El precio es de: " +total);
        }else
        if (area>500 && area<1000)
        {
            descuento = preciototal*.17;
            total = preciototal-descuento;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se aplica un descuento de: 17%"):
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El precio es de: " +total);
        }else
        if (area>1000)
        {
            descuento = preciototal*.25;
            total = preciototal-descuento;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se aplica un descuento de: 25%");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El precio es de: " +total);
        }else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se aplica descuento");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El precio es de: " +preciototal);
        }

    }
}
```

No se si esta bien o si se pueda realizar con Switch, gracias.

Comment: Sus estructuras de control no verifican valores menores que 400. Qué pasa si el valor es 500?

Answer (score 2):

### Respuesta corta

En estos casos, no conviene usar `switch`. Continúa usando `if-else`.

### Respuesta larga

En Java, la sentencia `switch` sirve para comparar valores estáticos en tiempo de compilación. Es decir, solo puedes usar `switch` cuando tienes **valores conocidos**. Por ejemplo:

```
int opcion = 0;
System.out.print("Ingrese opción: ");
opcion = //leer de input de usuario
switch (opcion) {
    case 1: //opción 1
        break;
    case 2: //opción 2
        break;
    default: //en caso que la opción no sea ni 1 ni 2
}
//resto del código...
```

Para el ejercicio que has colocado en tu pregunta, no se podría resolver estrictamente usando `switch`. Podrías forzar el uso de `switch` así:

```
int valor = 0;
if (area>400 && area<500) {
    valor = 1;
} else if (area>500 && area<1000) {
    valor = 2;
} else if (area>1000) {
    valor = 3;
}
switch(valor) {
    case 1:
        descuento = preciototal*.10;
        total = preciototal-descuento;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se aplica un descuento de: 10%");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El precio es de: " +total);
        break;
    case 2: //código...
        break;
    case 3:
        break;
    default:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas noches Carlos, totalmente de acuerdo con la anterior respuesta, quiero agregar algo a tu solución utilizando la condición, 
1. estas excluyendo la opción cuando son 400 o menos de 400 metros cuadrados y no hay descuento,
2. las condiciones deberían ser <= 400, >400 && <= 500,  >500 && <= 1000, y por ultimo > 1000
espero que esto te ayude un poco más

Comment: En realidad no lo está excluyendo. Hay una condición `else` luego de `valor >1000`